# Data doesn't load when I switch between router links

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a menubar with several router links. When I run ng serve in the command line my default route opens. Then when I click on a link of the menubar, I can see the data of the component, but as soon as I switch to another link and then back I can't see my data anymore? To prevent that I made a function that reloads my page everytime when I go to another link, but that isn't really the best solution. I tried to make something with the routerLinkActive, but that didn't solve my problem.

Here is my menubar html file:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="menubar">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <div *ngFor="let link of LINKS">
        <button mat-button (click)="reloadPage()"><a [routerLink]="link.linkUrl" class="link">{{link.linkName}}</a></button>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Here is my menubar ts file:

```
LINKS: NavigationInterface[];

  constructor(private linkService: NavigationServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.linkService.getLinks().subscribe(link => {
      this.LINKS = link;
    });
  }

  reloadPage() {
    location.reload();
  }
```

The interface of LINKS:

```
export interface NavigationInterface {
  linkName?: string;
  linkUrl?: string;
}
```

Here is the data:

```
linkName        | linkUrl
Home            | /home
Qualifikationen | /skills
```

Here is the html file of the data I want to display:

```
  <div *ngIf="SKILLS?.length > 0; else noItem">
    <div *ngFor="let skill of SKILLS | filter:skillGruppe">
      <div class="skill">
        <mat-accordion>
          <mat-expansion-panel>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-panel-title>{{skill.skillname}}
              </mat-panel-title>
              <mat-progress-bar class="progress-bar" [value]="skill.skillwert"></mat-progress-bar>
              <mat-panel-description>
              </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <div>{{skill.skillBeschreibung}}</div>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
        </mat-accordion>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the ts file of the data I want to display:

```
  SKILLS: IntCvSkill[];

  skillGruppe = 'Entwicklung';

  constructor(private skillService: CvServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.skillService.getSkills().subscribe(cvSkill => {
      this.SKILLS = cvSkill;
    });
  }

  filtereSkills(skillWert: string) {
    this.skillGruppe = skillWert;
  }
```

Here are my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'skills', component: SkillsComponent},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' }
];
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: can you share with us the route list ?

Comment: How have you setup dynamic routes? Check out https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/dynamic-routes-with-angular-6fda03b7fa2c

Comment: @UmutEsen I did that now, but the strange thing is, when I console log it, I get no data, so the data doesn't even fetch when I switch between the router links.

Comment: @despamigros is it your route look like this `/link/:id` ??

Comment: @malbarmawi to do that, I must see the data, but when the data doesn't load, it won't work...

Comment: @despamigros I got your routes can you share with us the `LINKS` ?

Comment: @malbarmawi there you go :)

Comment: @despamigros can you check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cpfo3e I don't figure out where is your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752380/how-can-i-call-a-constructor-when-i-change-my-route) question. I had to make a function that fetches my data when I subscribe to my data.

Here is my service:

```
export class CvServiceService {
  cvSkillCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<IntCvSkill>;
  cvSkill: Observable<IntCvSkill[]>;

  skillFilter: string;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) { }

  fetchingData() {
    this.cvSkillCollection = this.afs.collection('cv-skill');

    this.cvSkill = this.cvSkillCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as IntCvSkill;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    }));
  }

  getSkills() {
    this.fetchingData();
    return this.cvSkill;
  }

  skillFiltern(filterWert: string) {
    this.skillFilter = filterWert;
    return this.skillFilter;
  }

  addSkill(cvSkill: IntCvSkill) {
    this.cvSkillCollection.add(cvSkill);
  }

}
```