# How can I call a constructor when I change my route?

Tags: angular

When I switch between my routes, my data that I fetch from firebase doesn't load. The problem is, that when I enter the site, the constructor in my service get called and then when I switch between my router links, the constructor doesn't get called, ego my data doesn't load.

Here is my Service:

```
memberCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<MemberServiceService>;
  member: Observable<MembersInterface[]>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.memberCollection = this.afs.collection('members');

    this.member = this.memberCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as MembersInterface;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    }));
  }

  getMembers() {
    return this.member;
  }

  addMembers(memberAdd: any) {
    this.memberCollection.add(memberAdd);
  }
}
```

How can I call the constructor in my service after I switched between my routes?

Comment: Don't. You should use constructors for injection of dependencies but do not use them to initialize state by making service calls. I would redesign the service so that the body of the constructor is moved to a new method that you can call again when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thanks to Igor that brought me this Idea. Like he said I made a method that fetches my data and then get called when I need it.

Here is my code:

```
export class MemberServiceService {

  memberCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<MemberServiceService>;
  member: Observable<MembersInterface[]>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) { }

  fetchData() {

    this.memberCollection = this.afs.collection('members');

    this.member = this.memberCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as MembersInterface;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    }));
  }

  getMembers() {
    this.fetchData();
    return this.member;
  }


  addMembers(memberAdd: any) {
    this.memberCollection.add(memberAdd);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should read and understand the use of each Angular's life cycle, you can read about them in here:
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

I personally recommend:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(){
```

this.memberCollection = this.afs.collection('members');

```
this.member = this.memberCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
  return changes.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as MembersInterface;
    data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return data;
  });
}));     }
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but here is the problem that I can't subscribe. But the Idea would be good